# emacs & icicles: auto-completion from a dictionary?

Tags: emacs, dictionary, autocomplete, icicles

I just installed icicles with emacs, and so far I am liking it a lot. I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I would like to implement (or use, if it already exists) a feature in icicles that would auto-complete words from an English dictionary.

So, if I'm writing something and need a word that rhymes with `floor`, I can type in `*or`, or even better, for alliteration, type in `flo*` and have it return all the words from the dictionary that start with `flo`

Questions:

1. Does something like this exist?
2. If it does not exist, what would be the best way to go about this? Should I somehow hook into aspell? Or just index a long file of words?

*EDIT*: I suppose I am looking for something like synomyms.el, but with a dictionary. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with icicles and synonyms.el, for the most part.

use `M-x synonyms RET word-or-part-of-word S-TAB` and it will match words in the thesaurus and display them in a buffer.